# How to develop abstract thinking and problem solving skills?

Tags: self-learning, advice

I am currently doing post graduation in Industrial Mathematics. During my graduation years, I did not have much trouble in understanding the theorems or I should rather say, the arguments in the proofs (not the actual intuition and insight). Now that I have begun my post graduation, I really want to develop that all essential abstract way of thinking. For instance, while reading Rudin, even though I understand the proofs, I certainly do face difficulties while doing exercise problems. I realise that I have not developed my abstract thinking skills. Apart from the "prove that" type of problems, how important is it to develop problem solving skills for future mathematical endeavours? (like finding the sum of a given series)
I have realised that I really like reading and doing math and don't just want to get good grades but actually get a concrete understanding of the concepts, which is, of course, not possible without abstract thinking and "prove that" problems.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Blending apples and pears usually doesn't make anything useful.  But do it in your mind, look for the pros and cons, get weird conclusions. Don't be afraid of fool-thinking, it's a can of worms and also of brilliance. The point is not to get good results, but to develop your skills.

Comment: It would help to give a fuller citation for "while reading Rudin".  [Walter Rudin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Rudin) wrote books  with elegance not merely in proofs but in sequence of topics that affords graduate study in a highly self-contained manner.

Comment: Of course Rudin has written an amazing text, no questions about it. All I want to ask is how one develops the abstract thinking that is needed to get through Rudin and other advanced texts.